# AngularJS Accordion - add accordion heading style

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, styles, accordion

I have an accordion list based on [angular ui bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) like this:

```
<div ng-controller="AccordionCtrl">
<accordion close-others="oneAtTime">

<accordion-group is-open="l3payOpen">
    <accordion-heading>
    <span>
        <img class="marginleft" src="/web/bundles/lima3main/images/icon-l3play.png">
        L3 Pay
        <span class="img-submenu" ng-class="{'imgplus': !l3payOpen, 'imgminus': l3payOpen}"></span>
    </span>
    </accordion-heading>
    <ul class="accordion-ul">
        <li class="accordion-li" ng-class="{active:isActive('/singlepayment')}">
            <a href="#/singlepayment" id="single-payment">
                <img class="marginleft" src="/web/bundles/lima3main/images/icon-singlepayment.png">
                Single payment
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="accordion-li" ng-class="{active:isActive('/recurringbilling')}">
            <a href="#/recurringbilling" id="recurring-billing">
                <img class="marginleft" src="/web/bundles/lima3main/images/icon-recurringbilling.png">
                Recurring Billing
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</accordion-group>

<accordion-group is-disabled="true">
    <accordion-heading  >
        <span id="l3-bridge" ng-click="redirect('l3bridge')">
            <img class="marginleft" src="/web/bundles/lima3main/images/icon-l3bridge.png">
            L3 Bridge
        </span>
    </accordion-heading>
</accordion-group>


</accordion>
</div>
```

So, this accordion shows like this:

[image]

If you can see, there is an `ng-class` named isActive which **applies** in the `li tag` :

```
$scope.isActive = function(route) {
    return route === $location.path();
}
```

So when you click in any `li` the class works perfectly:

[image]

So, the problem is when I apply that ng-class in the other accordion groups which doesn't have the `li`s tag. And i can't apply it to span tag because the style shows like this:

[image]

Is there something that I can do ?